# QueryBuilder a ManyToMany to find all not in the jointable in Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have a ManyToMany relation in Doctrine, I created entities for table A and table B and Doctrine created a junction table C.

I'm trying to bring all results from table B that have no realtionship in table C.

Have tried many approaches but no success, about to remake this as a ManyToOne as last restor...

So far have tried using "MEMBER OF", native SQL, DQL, no success, can someone teach me how it works when querying when tables have attributes collection and not columns?

```
$query = $qb->select('a')
                ->innerJoin('a.clusters', 'c', Join::WITH, 'a.id = c.id')
                ->getQuery();
```

Return zero results :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sadegh Rohani insight, I was able to find the answer

```
$qb->select('a')
   ->leftJoin('a.c', 'c')
   ->where('c.id is null');
```

This querybuilder will find all entities a that do not belong to any c, which in manytomany relation is an arrayCollection attribute inside 'a' entity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$query = $qb->select('b')
        ->leftJoin('b.c', 'c')
        ->where('c.id != b.id')
         ->getQuery();
```

Comment: I used your approach and it's almost there, it's showing now only the entities that have relation, I needed the inverse of this...this is how I applied: return $qb->select('a')
            ->leftJoin('a.clusters', 'c')
            ->where('c.id != a.id')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();